# ReactJs - internationalization and wildcard replacements and html

Tags: reactjs, internationalization

I am looking to inherit a pre-built reactjs application - but I am concerned that the language json lines are split up - and instead of using replacement wildcards - also not sure how markup is being handled.

So really the message should read something like

```
'Hello {0} I am glad you have {1} your email is <a href=mailto:{2}>{2}</a>'
0 - "Johnny"
1 - "registered"
2 - "test@test.com"
```

this is what is currently on the repo.

[image]
[image]

Comment: possible to use this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react

Comment: <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: rawMarkup}} />

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zLt4y91u/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/remarkablemark/7v86d800/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=7v86d800

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zLt4y91u/

Comment: so I want something like {Utils.localised.message('component.cookie-message.text', "var1", "var2" )}     --- component.cookie-message.text = "I am a test for {0} and {1}"

Comment: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

json file

```
{
    "component.cookie.message": "Hey there {0}, how are {1}?"
}
```

translate

```
const lang = 'english';
const i18n = require(`./i18n/${lang}`);

module.exports = function translate (key, ...params) {
    return i18n[key].replace(/\{(\d)\}/g, function(match, number) {
        return params[number];
    });
}
```

index

```
const translate = require('./translate');

console.log(translate('component.cookie.message', 'Tom', 'you'));
```

Comment: <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: translate('component.cookie.message', 'Tom', 'you')}} />  - so would this be valid